# How to import sbt pack plugin to project

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I follow the [sbt-pack](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) link to import the plugin. I did:

1. add a line `addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-pack" % "0.7.5")` to `plugins.sbt` under my project root directory.
2. add a line `packAutoSettings` to the very top of `build.sbt` file under project root directory

then I run sbt to start the console, it said:

`error: not found: value packAutoSettings`

Also when I run sbt plugins, I don't see the new `sbt-pack` plugin shown on the list.

I also tried to create a file called pack.sbt and add content like:

`pack.settings
addSbtPlugin("org.xerial.sbt" % "sbt-pack" % "0.7.5")`

but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said that it's in your project root directory, if you mean that it's in

```
{your_project}/plugins.sbt
```

then that's not the correct place. It needs to be in

```
{your_project}/project/plugins.sbt
```

Comment: you are absolutely right. This is my first time using plugin so question might be silly. Anyway, Thank you!